Is logical necessity relative to specific logics?
Logical necessity is usually captured by the semantic entailment relation ‘⊨’. That is, “B is necessary for A” usually is interpreted as A⊨B. However, the semantic entailment relation only makes sense relative to a particular logic. So, are there multiple competing notions of logical necessity simpliciter, or is there just one kind of logical necessity?

Indeed in intuitionistic logics admissible but not derivable rules not unlike the cut rule in sequent calculus can be added to the system without causing inconsistency and imply a different weaker form of necessity because they reflect what can be consistently added rather than what can be constructively proven. In classical logics necessity is more about truth preservation across all models and worlds in an absolute fashion rather than constructive proof...

Of course, logical necessity depends on the logic used, different logics allow different sets of propositions to hold in their possible worlds. Why would you think otherwise?

@Conifold many people refer to logical possibility simpliciter as one set of consequences, whether implicitly or not.

See Kreisel squeezing argument. Also here
